# Error in using Roboto font in button

Tags: android, eclipse, button

I am writing an app where I want to use the Roboto thin font in the buttons. This is the code I have in the onCreate method in the main activity:

```java
Typeface roboto = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Roboto-thin.ttf"); 

    btn1.setTypeface(roboto);
    btn2.setTypeface(roboto);
    btn3.setTypeface(roboto);
    btn4.setTypeface(roboto);
    btn5.setTypeface(roboto);
    btn6.setTypeface(roboto);
    btn7.setTypeface(roboto);
    btn8.setTypeface(roboto);
    btn9.setTypeface(roboto);
    btnd.setTypeface(roboto);
    btn1x.setTypeface(roboto);

    btnAdd.setTypeface(roboto);
    btnSub.setTypeface(roboto);
    btnDiv.setTypeface(roboto);
    btnMul.setTypeface(roboto);
    btnPow.setTypeface(roboto);
    btnEqu.setTypeface(roboto);
    btnDel.setTypeface(roboto);
    btnAC.setTypeface(roboto);
```

For some reason, the app crashes when it is run. I have the file Robot-Thin.ttf in the assets folder. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: would like to see the logcat

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I just figured out the problem. When I declared the typeface, I called the file "Roboto-thin.ttf" instead of the file "Roboto-Thin.ttf," showing that it really is case sensitive when calling those files.